# IntelliJ moving my mouse cursor in random positions

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, mouse-cursor

IntelliJ sometimes moves the cursor on default positions, like over the `Find` button when you do a `Find in Path`.

However recently it is moving my cursor to completely random positions. I suspect this is because of my multi-monitor setup.

A computer/IntelliJ restart doesn't fix the issue.

How can I disable this "automatic move" thing entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can disable "automatic moves" by `Settings > Appearance & Behavior >  Appearance`, checkbox `Automatically position cursor on default button`. [Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/appearance.html)

---

**Edit (2021-02-15):** Something changed in the UI in recent versions. If you're having trouble finding the option you can edit the registry.

> Here is the request for missing option:
> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99985
>
> The option should be disabled though.  Try checking
> `focus.follows.mouse.workarounds` in registry.

You can open the registry by searching all Actions for `Registry`, then edit that value.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> and select "Registry" from the menu that appears.

Then set `ide.settings.move.mouse.on.default.button` value to disable.

[Registry dialog image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HBiX.png)

Answer (score 1):

From the official Intellij documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/appearance.html#d1207234e126

[image]

To disable this quickly in Intellij 15 and newer (which have the '[Search Everywhere](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/searching-everywhere.html)' feature), do the following:

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
2. Type `UI: auto`. This should popup the following:
   [image]
3. Highlight that option and press enter.